# Ant matcher ending with

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need an ant matcher for my spring security config. This matcher should match following urls

- /health
- /contolller/health

Now i had this one  `.antMatchers("/health").permitAll()` but this rejects `/contolller/health`

Then i tried `.antMatchers("/*/health").permitAll()` but this rejects `/health`

So any suggestions ?

P.S. i'd like to use antMatchers method, not regexMatchers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.antMatchers("/health")`refers only to the specific ant.

You can add "/**"`.antMatchers("/controller/**")` to refer to all of its subfolders

You can add "**/" before /health `.antMatchers("/**/health")` to match "health" directories that are located anywhere or `.antMatchers("/**/health/**")` to match all files in "health" directories that are located anywhere

or else write all the specific subfolders `.antMatchers("/health", "/contoller/health")` with comma.

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple `.antMatchers()` or you can add multiple endpoints in one `antmatcher`

If you don't filter your `.antmatcher()` using `.hasRole()` or `.hasAuthority()`, you can just use multiple endpoint in one `antmatcher`

```
.antMatchers("/health", "/contolller/health").permitAll()
```

But, if you have `.hasRole()` or `.hasAuthority()` you can just add multiple `antmatchers`

```
.antMatchers("/health").hasRole("ROLE_ADMIN");
.antMatchers("/contolller/health").hasRole("ROLE_EMPLOYEE")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. That's really useful. But i mark Fotiou's answer as right just because he was the first c:

Comment: Glad to help, I don't really care. What's more important is that you solved your problem. Cheers!